# Get the parent ListView contol of a listitem vb6/vba

Tags: vba, listview, vb6

I need a function in vba/vb6 that returns the ListView control of a listitem when I pass the listitem as argument of that function.

Comment: From a search that I have done until now I thing that only with API call can be done... but I do not know the details... I know that the listview control is a window and the listitem is a child of that window...

Comment: could you please show what do you have to pass as argument? If you mean ListView of CommonControls, then I believe `listitems` aren't windowed...

Comment: Function GetListView(Item As ListItem) As ListView.
Yes I know that listitem is not windowed... But it is a child of ListView window....

Comment: look for the `ListItem` member in the Object Browser, you will find the `key` property. so i believe you have to ensure this key is unique among all ListViews you have in your project, or - maybe better - you can set the `Tag` property in such way for that purpose, by hashing ListView.Name/Index + ListItem.Key

Comment: You are right....If I set the Tag property of a listitem to its parent ListView.name every time a listitem created  maybe it will work but this method is not portal. To work this function implies this, and this is not a way of portability. Also you have to create the object ListView from its name to return it. With all these the function has too many dependencies and losts its purpose: the Independent operation. It looks like I pass the ListView as argument and return it again...!!! What's the point?

Comment: Simply pass the control and the item to your function, there is no link between a ListItem (LVITEM) and its parent.

Comment: Alex K.
This is how I have it now... I thought it could be more general but maybe you are right...